# What happens if the DDL statement will crashes? (Oracle DB)

Tags: sql, oracle, crash, ddl

the question is: 
 I performed only DML statements and I'll try to perform DDL statement, but what 
 happens if the DDL fails? Will there be a rollback of only the DDL, or DML too?

Like this:

```
-- point 1

 INSERT ...

 INSERT ...

 INSERT ...
```

**// 3 inserted rows**

```
-- point 2

CREATE ... (crash)
```

What point will it return? point 1 or point 2?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try it and see, it's not hard to 'crash' a `create`

Comment: what are point 1 and point 2, commits? Also the DDL is an implicit commit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A DDL will implicitly commit your transaction even if it fails, here is an exemple from Ask tom:

```
create table t (
  x int
);

insert into t values (1);

alter table t add (x varchar2(10)); -- duplicate column

SQL Error: ORA-01430: column being added already exists in table

rollback;

select * from t;

X  
1
```

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9532421900346923086